# How can I change the color of label when focus on input?

Tags: html, css

This is my CSS code:

```css
.textOnInput input {
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(150, 150, 150);
}

.textOnInput input:focus {
    color: red;
    outline: none !important;
    border-color: purple;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.textOnInput {
    position: relative;
}

.textOnInput label {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 2px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.textOnInput label:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}

label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: .5rem;
}
```

and this is my HTML code:

```html
<div class="textOnInput">
    <label for="inputText">Email</label>
    <input type="text"/>
</div>
```

How can I change "Email" Color when I focus on input?
Label should change color from white to red when I focus on input.

Comment: border's color will change but label color not.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this
using Flex box will solve this. Have the label element follow the input element in the HTML. Then use flex-direction: column-reverse to change its position to appear above the input element. You can then use the `input:focus + label: {}` to target the label.

```css
.input-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.input-container>input {
  /* your input styles */
}

.input-container>input:focus+label {
  /* targets the label when the input receives focus */
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-container">
  <input type='email' />
  <label>Email</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this ?

[image]

```
.textOnInput input {
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(150, 150, 150);
}

#focus:hover ,#text:focus{
    color: red;
    outline: none !important;
    border-color: purple;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.textOnInput {
    position: relative;
}


.textOnInput label:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}

label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: .5rem;
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" >

</head>
<body>
    <div class="textOnInput">
        <label id="focus" for="inputText">Email</label>
        <input id="text" type="text" value="email@mail.com"/>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No Actually I want to change "Email" color to red after focus.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so muchhhh, But I had another problem that it was in HTML code too...

I had to write input line first then label line.

I mean:

```
<label for="inputText">Email</label>
<input type="text"/>
```

To:

```
<input type="text"/>
<label for="inputText">Email</label>
```

Thanks for helping :P

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 CSS selectors that allow for styling adjacent elements. They are `+` and `~`, with the first one styling the immediate next sibling, and the second one styling all siblings that come later.

So for example, if you have 3 elements like this:

```
<style>
  div {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
  }

  #main + div {
    background: crimson;
  }

  #main ~ div {
    background: steelblue;
  }
</style>

<div id="main"></div>
<div id="siblingOne" class="sibling"></div>
<div id="siblingTwo" class="sibling"></div>
```

`#main + div` will apply styles only to `#siblingOne`, whereas `#main ~ div` will apply styles to both `#siblingOne` and `#siblingTwo`.

The problem we have is that the sibling selectors only apply forwards. That is, you cannot select an element before `#main` with this.

So to apply this to your problem, you should structure your HTML in such a way that the `<label>` comes after `<input>`. And then you can display all of them as flex (the container, and both it's children), and use the `order` property to render it the way you originally wanted to.

Here is a snippet of how it will look:

```css
* { font-family: sans-serif; }

.textOnInput input {
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(150, 150, 150);
    order: 1; /* This is important */
    display: flex; /* This is important */
}

.textOnInput {
    display: flex; /* This is important */
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}

label {
    display: flex; /* This is important */
    order: 0; /* This is important */
    margin-right: 5px;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input:focus + label {
    color: red;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="textOnInput">
    <input type="text" id="inputText"/>
    <label for="inputText">Email: </label>
</div>
```